# I want to add and delete a large number of numbers using a ArrayList in c#

Tags: c#

I want to know the performance of 'arraylist' when I input a large number.

'arraylist' adding is work well. but it takes a lot of time when remove the 'arraylist'.

for example when i input the number '10000000' adding is work rapidly.
removing takes about 15 minutes.

how to fix it?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
    HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
    SortedList sortedList = new SortedList();
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    Queue queue = new Queue();

    static List<string > list = new List<string>() ;
    static Random rand = new Random(50000);

    static long count = 0;
    static  string inputCount = "";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inputCount = countTextbox.Text;
        count = Convert.ToInt64(inputCount);
    }


    private void arrayListBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list.Add($"T_{i.ToString("000000000")}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
        }
        foreach (var item in list.ToList())
        {
            arrayList.Add(rand);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(arrayList.Count);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        arrayListAddTextBox.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();

        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();

        foreach (var item in list.ToList())
        {
            arrayList.Remove(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(arrayList.Count);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        arrayListRemoveTextBox.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use an `ArrayList`? `List<T>` Is much better and supports generics. It is almost always the better choice.

Comment: I just test the arraylist for the study. and i will update hasttable hashset sortedlist ...

Comment: @HyunsooKim Is it important that you use `Remove()` with the `object`/`T` argument? Can you use `RemoveAt()` instead, specially when you remove from the end?

Comment: @Progman it's ok, using RemoveAt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to fix it?

To fix what? `ArrayList` works this way. Internal it contains array, so remove will copy some data from one part of array to another. So, if you remove from beginning, it will move all except one element.

Also, `ArrayList` will waste time for [boxing/unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing), because `ArrayList` store data as `object`.
Also, to find element to remove takes many time.

More data you can find in [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs).

If you need to add and remove - find better collection for it. Like `HashSet<>`.

Comment: ", so any remove will recreate internal array and copy all data to the new one" is [obviously false](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,3e3f6715773d6643)... Are you sure that is what you wanted to say?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, thanks. `ArrayList` is little better than I thought before